# OOP maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a weird situation with OOP

My class is very simple

```
class Thing{

  private
    $children = array(),
    $parent;


  public function addChild(self $thing){
    $this->children[] = $thing;
    $thing->setParent($this);
  }

  public function setParent(self $thing){
    $this->parent = $thing;
    $thing->addChild($this);
  }

}


$a = new Thing();
$b = new Thing();

$b->setParent($a);
```

If I try to use these functions I get the Maximum function nesting level of 100 error and I know why, but how am I supposed to change the code? The way it is now it makes sense, but if I remove any of the function calls it would not work like it should.

Comment: Your code does not make sense. Once either of the methods is called, it calls the other one which calls the first one which calls the other one which calls the first one ... When will this ever stop?

Comment: I don't get why you addChild in the setParent method and setParent in the addChild method.

Comment: They are needed to create relationships

Comment: Your code creates an infinite loop with each function calling the other until PHP dies. The solution is to re-think your functions, because right now they: 1. Make no sense. 2. Break PHP.

Comment: basically: either always use setChild, or always use setParent, but don't use both. Generally APIs keep `addChild` as calling `setParent`, but don't make `setParent` call `addChild`, since at that point this is already implied.

Comment: Do you want to be able to call either `addChild()` or `setParent()` and in doing so enforce the relationship on both objects? It can be done and solve the infinite loop by just adding an `if()` inside `setChild()` to check if the parent is already set to `$this`.

Comment: A pending closevote for "too broad" is ridiculous, people. This is a specific question with a specific solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your code creates an infinite loop between `setParent()` and `addChild()`, wherein a call to `setParent()` implicitly also calls `setChild()`, which in turn calls `setParent()` again.

If you want your code to work such that a call to `setParent()` *or* a call to `addChild()` enforces the relationship in properties in *both* objects, you can solve the infinite loop you are currently experiencing by adding an `if ()` condition inside `addChild()`, calling `setParent()` only if the object's parent is not already the current object (`$this`).

Likewise, you  need to check if the object to be added as a child in `addChild()` has not already been added to the parent's `$children` array using `in_array()`.

```
class Thing{

  private
    $children = array(),
    $parent;
  // A name property just to see the results
  public $name;


  public function addChild(self $thing){
    $this->children[] = $thing;

    // Only set this object to the passed-in $thing object's
    // $parent property if it has not already been set:
    if ($thing->parent !== $this) {
      $thing->setParent($this);
    }   
  }

  public function setParent(self $thing){
    $this->parent = $thing;

    // Only add the child via addChild() if it is not
    // already in the array
    if (!in_array($this, $thing->children)) {
      $thing->addChild($this);
    }
  }

}

$a = new Thing();
$a->name = "THING A";
$b = new Thing();
$b->name = "THING B";
// Specify $a as the parent of $b
$b->setParent($a);

echo "\$a properties:\n";
print_r($a);
echo "\$b properties:\n";
print_r($b);
```

The output from the above is:

```
$a properties:
Thing Object
(
    [children:Thing:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thing Object
                (
                    [children:Thing:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [parent:Thing:private] => Thing Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [name] => THING B
                )

        )

    [parent:Thing:private] => 
    [name] => THING A
)
$b properties:
Thing Object
(
    [children:Thing:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [parent:Thing:private] => Thing Object
        (
            [children:Thing:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Thing Object
 *RECURSION*
                )

            [parent:Thing:private] => 
            [name] => THING A
        )

    [name] => THING B
)
```

Now, using the *inverse* action, starting with `$a` and `$b` then adding `$b` as a child to `$a` instead of adding `$a` as the parent of `$b`:

```
$a = new Thing();
$a->name = "THING A";
$b = new Thing();
$b->name = "THING B";
// Add $b as a child of $a
$a->addChild($b);
```

Produces the same output:

```
$a properties:
Thing Object
(
    [children:Thing:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Thing Object
                (
                    [children:Thing:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [parent:Thing:private] => Thing Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [name] => THING B
                )

        )

    [parent:Thing:private] => 
    [name] => THING A
)
$b properties:
Thing Object
(
    [children:Thing:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [parent:Thing:private] => Thing Object
        (
            [children:Thing:private] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Thing Object
 *RECURSION*
                )

            [parent:Thing:private] => 
            [name] => THING A
        )

    [name] => THING B
)
```

(Note about the "RECURSION" in the `print_r()` output: That does not indicate the method calls are behaving recursively, just that there is a recursive relationship between the object references, which is what you want. `$a` has a child `$b` and `print_r()` attempts to display the parent of `$b`, which points back to `$a`)